# How to Properly Implement runOnUiThread Android

Tags: android, textview, android-runonuithread

I need to use the runOnUiThread to update a TextView in the UI while within a worker thread which gets some strings from a webservice. I have looked at some other posts here and tried to implement the solutions offered, but when I start my app it crashes. I am not too familiar with this method, so I need some direction as to how to solve this issue.

> 04-25 12:19:59.917 4108-4108/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>   04-25 12:19:59.917 4108-4108/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
>   04-25 12:20:00.147 4108-4108/com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2-2/lib/x86
>   04-25 12:20:00.154 4108-4108/com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   04-25 12:20:00.218 4108-4108/com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   04-25 12:20:00.218 4108-4108/com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2, PID: 4108
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2/com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:33)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:33)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
>                                                                                       at com.example.gmars.parseltonguev2.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:30)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

```
Activity updateUI;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    updateUI = this;

    itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    new GetItemAvailability().execute();

}

@Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler handler = new HttpHandler();

        String JSON_DATA = handler.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + JSON_DATA);

        if (JSON_DATA != null) {
            JSON_DATA = JSON_DATA.substring(JSON_DATA.indexOf('{'),JSON_DATA.lastIndexOf('}')+1);
            Log.e(TAG, "Substring of response: " + JSON_DATA);
            try {
                JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);

                JSONObject availability = reader.getJSONObject("availability");

                final String availableQuantity = availability.getString("availableQuantity");
                final String defaultBranch = availability.getString("defaultBranch");
                final String defaultInventoryBranch = availability.getString("defaultInventoryBranch");
                final String inventoryBranch = availability.getString("inventoryBranch");
                final String footage = availability.getString("footage");
                final String anticipatedStockDate = availability.getString("anticipatedStockDate");
                final String discontinuedItemFlag = availability.getString("discontinuedItemFlag");
                final String mdc = availability.getString("mdc");
                final String mdcquantity = availability.getString("mdcquantity");

                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();

                item.put("availableQuantity", availableQuantity);
                item.put("defaultBranch", defaultBranch);
                item.put("defaultInventoryBranch", defaultInventoryBranch);
                item.put("inventoryBranch", inventoryBranch);
                item.put("footage", footage);
                item.put("anticipatedStockDate", anticipatedStockDate);
                item.put("discontinuedItemFlag", discontinuedItemFlag);
                item.put("mdc", mdc);
                item.put("mdcquantity", mdcquantity);

                itemList.add(item);

                updateUI.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvAvailableQuantity.setText(availableQuantity);
                        tvDefaultBranch.setText(defaultBranch);
                        tvDefaultInventoryBranch.setText(defaultInventoryBranch);
                        tvInventoryBranch.setText(inventoryBranch);
                        tvFootage.setText(footage);
                        tvAnticipatedStockDate.setText(anticipatedStockDate);
                        tvDiscontinuedItemFlag.setText(discontinuedItemFlag);
                        tvMdc.setText(mdc);
                        tvMdcquantity.setText(mdcquantity);
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: you must initialize UI variables, for example `TextView tvAvailableQuantity = (TestView) findViewById(id)`

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the stacktrace of the crash? Possibly it has nothing to do with `runOnUiThread()` and it will give us more info.

Comment: I have done that just before the onCreate method with my other variables. I only posted snippets of the code concerning the runOnUiThread. Thanks.

Comment: the please add the stacktrace...

Comment: I added the stack trace.

Comment: Where do you initialize the view variables, such as `tvAvailableQuantity`? You can only look them up with `findViewById()` after the call to `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I had my TextViews initialized before the onCreate method. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of runOnUiThread() is correct. You pass it a runnable which is run on the UI thread.

In your case however, I think this is not even necessary if you change the result type of your AsyncTask to String, you can simply return `JSON_DATA` from the `doInBackground()` method and move the rest of the code into `onPostExecute()` which runs on the UI thread anyways.

Comment: Thank you, I had my TextViews initialized before onCreate. However, which is better practice, to use runOnUiThread or your method?

Comment: Normally, you use runOnUiThread if you need to e.g. show something to the user while you're in the middle of doing something in a different thread. In your case, your network access (which demanded the separate thread in the first place) is already over, so in this case I'd say that my suggestion would be preferable here - it is also easier to read, a bit shorter and you do not need to create the Runnable object.